# What triggers an onAfterAction in IronRouter other than a route change?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm having trouble debugging an `onAfterAction` that I don't want to run. It happens when I click a certain div. `Router.go` is not being called (verified with `debugger;` in the iron router code), and the URL is not changing. I can't find anything in my click handlers that would cause a route change. The `onAfterAction` happens from a deps invalidation:

```
Router.configure.onAfterAction (routes.coffee:5)
RouteController.runHooks (route_controller.js:155)
(anonymous function) (route_controller.js:291)
RouteController.runHooks (route_controller.js:158)
(anonymous function) (route_controller.js:283)
Deps.Computation._compute (deps.js:196)
Deps.Computation._recompute (deps.js:210)
Deps.flush (deps.js:304)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking the div caused the User doc to change. There was global `onBeforeAction` that checked to see if the user was logged in (`if Meteor.user()`), which is reactive and triggered a rerun of `action` and `onAfterAction`. I changed it to `if Meteor.userId()`, which did not get invalidated when updating the user doc.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have some reactive data source in onAfterAction (`cursor`, `Session` object).
It will rerun every time reactive data source will be changed.

You can forbid this behavior by wrapping function in `onAfterAction` :

```
Tracker.nonreactive(function(){})
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but the problem remains. Any suggestions for further diagnosis?

Comment: @KubaWyrobek i tried your approach but it didn't work for me.  I'm using Tracker.afterFlush(function () {}). i also changed the Meteor.user() to Meteor.userId(). 
View getting loaded but url not get flushed.